# Python: how to extend execution time of code to 1 second

Tags: python, time

I'm writing a countdown clock in python, but it looks like the time module only goes down to the second. Is there a way for me to accurately determine when exactly 1 second has passed?

Seems like my question was a little confusing, let me clarify. I need to run some code, then, at the end, the program enters a while loop and exits once at least 1000 milliseconds have passed since the time the code started running

Comment: did you try the datetime module? specifically check out the timedelta object

Comment: [Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) objects.

Comment: Timer won't really work for what I'm doing, because I need to run some code then wait until the remainder of the second has passed. I don't want to wait a second and then run the code, because then it will be off

Comment: Then use `time.sleep` in conjunction with `time.time`

Comment: Remember, precision and accuracy are two different things. Fallenreaper's answer will give you subsecond precision, but I suspect you'll be disappointed in the accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *know* the code you want to run will take less than 1 second, then `1 - elapsed time` will give you the remaining time to sleep, no `while` loop required.

```
now = time.time()
foo()
time.sleep(1 - (time.time() - now))
```

There will be some overhead with the arithmetic, but it's within 1/100 of a second and will be strictly greater than 1 second, as you request. I ran the following code:

```
import time
import random

def foo():
    time.sleep(random.random())

now = time.time()
foo()
time.sleep(1 - (time.time() - now))

print "Time elapsed: {}".format(time.time() - now)
```

Output:

```
Time elapsed: 1.00379300117
```

You can run this several times to verify it gives the output you want, no matter how long `foo` takes.

Unless it takes longer than 1 second, then the sleep time will be negative which will result in `IOError`. You would need to check for that case.

Or, if you need to kill the function if 1 second has passed, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way which will work, though im not sure which modules you are limited to.

```
import time

def procedure:
    time.sleep(2.5)

# measure wall time
t0 = time.time()
procedure()
print time.time() - t0, "seconds wall time"
```

*2.50023603439 seconds wall time*

where procedure is a reference to the function you are timing.

Answer (score -1):

By default the [`time`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module gives you the time to the 10^-5 second

```
import time
time.time()
>>> 1480643510.89443
```